# Javascript: Push an object into an array inside another array by internal array's key

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a months array that has 12 dynamically created objects for the next 12 months

```
 months = [
    {2020-02: Array(0)}
    {2020-03: Array(0)}
    {2020-04: Array(0)}
    {2020-05: Array(0)}
    {2020-06: Array(0)}
    {2020-07: Array(0)}
    {2020-08: Array(0)}
    {2020-09: Array(0)}
    {2020-10: Array(0)}
    {2020-11: Array(0)}
    {2020-12: Array(0)}
    {2021-01: Array(0)}
    ];
```

I want to insert an object into the object's array based on a dynamic key that is based on another array (source data).

I loop through the source data and each object in the source data's array has a key of media_date and value of 2020-02;

I then create an object to insert into the months array

```
var person = new Object();
person.title = 'job title';
person.name = 'cool name';
```

I want to insert the person object into the months array into the object with the key of 2020-02

I tried something like:

```
$.each(source,function(i,data){
    var person = new Object();
    person.title = data.job_title;
    person.name = data.name;
  var key = data.monthyear (2020-02)
  months.[key].push(person);
});
```

But I get

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined at...

Thanks for any help you can give!

Comment: in js has this syntax `months.[key]`?

Comment: `months[key].push(person);`, you don't need the '.' (dot) between months and your key

Comment: `months[key] = person?`

Comment: syntax error months.[key] and keys with hypen is not a good idea change to "2021-01" or 2020101

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the months array is:

```
months = [
{'2020-02': Array(0)},
{'2020-03': Array(0)},
{'2020-04': Array(0)},
{'2020-05': Array(0)},
{'2020-06': Array(0)},
{'2020-07': Array(0)},
{'2020-08': Array(0)},
{'2020-09': Array(0)},
{'2020-10': Array(0)},
{'2020-11': Array(0)},
{'2020-12': Array(0)},
{'2021-01': Array(0)}
];
```

`findMonth = '2020-02';`

use one of the following to find the position of the wanted object:

- `index = months.findIndex(x => Boolean(x[findMonth]))`
- `index = months.findIndex(x => Object.keys(x)[0] === findMonth)`

then use the following to push at the value of the key
`months[index][findMonth].push(person)`